# Line Integral Symmetry Trick

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

(I was wondering how to use the given hint in this question.)

Evaluate 
$$
\int_L \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\, ds
$$

where $L$ is the straight line $Ax+By=C$, $C\ne 0$.

*Hint:* use the symmetry of the integrand to replace the line with a line having a simpler equation but giving the same value to the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetry of $x^2+y^2$ under rotation means
$$
\int_L\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,\mathrm{d}s=\int_{L'}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,\mathrm{d}s
$$
where $L'$ is any other line with the same perpendicular distance from $0$.  In particular, you may choose (say) the horizontal line $y=c$, where $c=C/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$.
So
$$
\int_L\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,\mathrm{d}s=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+c^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
which is easy to calculate.